# How can I show values close to 0 as my formatted 0 display?

Tags: excel, formatting

Sorry if the title wasn't very clear for what my question is.

My problem is that I am trying to reconcile a few different files in excel, but due to some rounding errors the values sometimes come out as really small values like .0001.

My current number format that I've put together that I like to use is `#,##0_);(#,##0);"-"` which rounds to whole numbers and replaces 0 with a dash.  However when a value comes out small like .0001 my number format rounds it to 0 and displays either 0 or (0) depending on if it is positive or negative.  This leaves my final summary page having intermittent 0, (0), and - which is just kind of ugly to me.

So I was wondering if there was something I could add to my number format or do in conditional formatting to display small values close to 0 as a - like they were actually 0?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: a conditional formatting rule based on something like `=abs(a1)<0.005` should be appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional formatting.

Add a rule that has custom format of:

```
0;0;0 #if you want 0 to be shown instead of small value
```

And condition should be:

```
=ABS(A1)<0.01 #for example
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for conditional formatting.  You can use regular number formatting with a custom code.

If your boundary condition will be `0 +/- 0.01`, you can use a number format of:

```
[<-0.01]-0;[>0.01]0;0
```

And you can use more complex formatting, if you want.

[image]